# Handling OSM Data for whole country

Tags: r, openstreetmap

Is there any way to get the data matching the filters given for the `osmdata`- library for a whole country or another big part? The problem is if the area is getting bigger, the file is too large and the download aborts.  Below is the import section I'm using right now.

```r
library(osmdata)

q <- getbb("Germany") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature("amenity", "restaurant")

str(q) #query structure
cinema <- osmdata_sf(q)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the Planet.osm file I can tell you that there are about 97.000 objects, way or node, with tag `amenity = "restaurant"` in Germany. The OSM-API won't handle that. You'll even get a timeout using overpass-turbo.

For large amounts of data you'll have to download the [Planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) file into a database. You'll find a nice tutorial [here](https://www.r-spatial.org/2017/07/14/large_scale_osm_in_r)

Comment: Good approach - but any idea how I do something similar without the need for Java? (Due to restrictive IT security constraints.)